# How can I connect to one server using two user names - at the same time?

Tags: finder, sharing, file-sharing

I am struggling to find a way to allow users to connect to two different shares on a server at the same time. It seems like it should be possible, but no matter what I try I am always forced to disconnect one user to connect as another.

I have tried using aliases like this:

```
afp://user1:password1@ServerName._afpovertcp._tcp.local
afp://user2:password2@ServerName._afpovertcp._tcp.local
```

The first one connected works, and the second one ignores the name/password when connecting and just offers to connect as the first user again.

Is there a user friendly way to make this work?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not *entirely* sure it would work, but try this, from Terminal:

```
mkdir /Volumes/foo /Volumes/bar
mount -t afp afp://foo:foopass@ServerName._afpovertcp._tcp.local /Volumes/foo
mount -t afp afp://bar:barpass@ServerName._afpovertcp._tcp.local /Volumes/bar
```

Answer (score 2):

You can always cheat and use a different protocol for the second connection.  OS X works with SMB.